# NDSolveValue -difference between Version 11.2 and Version 11.3

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, heat-equation

I am trying to learn something about simulation of heat transfer by looking at [this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/120052/12558) which is an answer by user21. If I try this in Version 11.3 the following happens:

```
$VersionNumber
```

> 11.3

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]   
tdiff[z_] := 0.5 + 0.1 UnitStep[z - 1] + 0.2 UnitStep[z - 2];

eqn = tdiff[z]*D[u[t, r, z],t] - 
(D[u[t, r, z], z, z] + (1/r) D[r D[u[t, r, z], r], r]);
Ω = ImplicitRegion[True, {{r, 0.001, 200}, {z, 0, 3}}];

   sol = NDSolveValue[{
   eqn == NeumannValue[30 - u[t, r, z], z == 0],
   DirichletCondition[u[t, r, z] == 35, z == 3],
   DirichletCondition[u[t, r, z] == 0, r == 200],
   u[0, r, z] == 0},
  u, {t, 0, 1000}, {r, z} ∈ Ω]
```

There are error messages related to NDSolveValue the first of which is:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, if I repeat the above in

```
$VersionNumber
```

> 11.2

I do get a solution.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which I can plot as

```
   Animate[Plot3D[sol[t, r, z], {r, z} ∈ Ω, 
  PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 35}}], {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image: fig1]

Is there something changed in version 11.3?

Comment: Workaround,with this: `\[CapitalOmega] = ImplicitRegion[True, {{r, 1/1000, 200}, {z, 0, 3}}];` works.

Comment: Version 12.1 has a tutorial on [Heat Transfer Modeling](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a quick fix you could use generate the mesh with `ToElementMesh` first:

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega], RegionBounds[\[CapitalOmega]]]
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqn == NeumannValue[30 - u[t, r, z], z == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[u[t, r, z] == 35, z == 3], 
   DirichletCondition[u[t, r, z] == 0, r == 200], u[0, r, z] == 0}, 
  u, {t, 0, 1000}, {r, z} \[Element] mesh]
```

or, as suggested in a comment use an exact region representation in your original code:

```
\[CapitalOmega] = ImplicitRegion[True, {{r, 1/1000, 200}, {z, 0, 3}}];
```

I'd need to look a bit closer to see what is going on in your case. Sorry about that.

These two function calls should return the same but they do not and that is a bug I'll report:

```
Region`Mesh`BoundariesToBoundaryMeshRegion[{0.001 - x <= 
    0 && -200 + x <= 0 && -y <= 0 && -3 + y <= 0}, {x, 1/1000, 
  200}, {y, 0, 3}]
```

and

```
Region`Mesh`BoundariesToBoundaryMeshRegion[{1/1000 - x <= 0 && -200 + x <= 0 && -y <= 0 && -3 + y <= 0}, {x, 1/1000, 200}, {y, 0, 3}]
```

Comment: Thanks, got me going again as usual.

Comment: @Hugh, glad I could help. The fix for the code should make it into the sources today and then a next release will have the fix for you. Sorry for the trouble and thanks for reporting.